# Read properties of options builder in IServiceCollection extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, startup

I have an extension method on `IServiceCollection` that looks like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyProjData(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyProjDataOptionsBuilder> optionsBuilder)
{
    services.Configure(optionsBuilder);

    services.AddDbContext<MyProjDbContext>(contextOptions => contextOptions
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseMySql("?????")
    );

    return services;
}
```

The class `MyProjOptionsBuilder` looks like this:

```
public class MyProjDataOptionsBuilder
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get to the property `ConnectionString` inside my extension method?

I want to do something like this:

```
var connectionString = optionsBuilder().ConnectionString;
```

---

PS.

I know I can directly pass a `string` as parameter instead of an `Action` to the extension method `AddMyProjData`. But in my real project I need to set a lot more settings than just one `ConnectionString`.

I also like the style of using an `Action` to configure the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create an instance of `MyProjDataOptionsBuilder` inside `AddMyProjData`, apply `optionsBuilder` against *that* instance and then use the properties you need.

Here's an example:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyProjData(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<MyProjDataOptionsBuilder> optionsBuilder)
{
    var myProjDataOptionsBuilder = new MyProjDataOptionsBuilder();
    optionsBuilder(myProjDataOptionsBuilder);

    services.Configure(optionsBuilder);

    services.AddDbContext<MyProjDbContext>(contextOptions => contextOptions
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseMySql(myProjDataOptionsBuilder.ConnectionString)
    );

    return services;
}
```

There's some repetition in terms of what's going on here (invoking `optionsBuilder` twice), but I wouldn't expect this to be a great cost overall.

An alternative would be to separate your configuration-time and your runtime options - I doubt you're going to need the connection-string itself anywhere other than inside of your extension method, but I'm only guessing here.

---

From what you've shown in your OP, I'm not convinced that `MyProjDataOptionsBuilder` is a great name (I'd probably just go with `MyProjDataOptions`), but that's mostly an aside here.